# Attaching a node to a table cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I use the following code to draw a table, with a red rectangle around a cell; and a text referring to this cell.

But this code neither give me a control of the slide on which the rectangle is displayed, nor of the position of the arrow and text in relation to the targeted cell.

I would like to draw the rectangle on slide 2 with a node attached to it containing the arrow and text instead of drawing and aligning them manually. If possible with a tikzset to control the x and y relation between the node and rectangle according to the position of the targeted cell inside the table.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % suppress navigation bar
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, shapes, fit, shapes.misc}
\newcommand\marktopleft[1]{
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-#1-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};
}
\newcommand\markbottomright[1]{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
\node (marker-#1-b) at (0,0) {};
 \tikz[overlay, remember picture, thick, red, inner sep=3pt]
 \node[draw, rounded rectangle, fit=(marker-#1-a.center) (marker-#1-b.center)] {};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\hspace {-1.cm}
\begin{tabular}{*6{c}}\hline
  A & B & C & D & E & F \\
 A1 & B1 & \marktopleft{c1}C1\markbottomright{c1} & D1 & E1 & F1 \\
 A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 & E2 & F2 \\
 A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 & E3 & F3 \\
 A4 & B4 & C4 & D4 & E4 & F4 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace {-3.cm}
\draw<2-> [ultra thick, red, -latex'] (0,0) -- +(180:3.36) node [text width=2.2cm, draw=red, very thick, fill=red!15!white, align=center, xshift=4.5cm, yshift=0cm, rounded corners=5pt] {\bf Appreciation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % suppress navigation bar
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,overlay-beamer-styles,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\hspace {-1.cm}
\begin{tabular}{*6{c}}\hline
  A & B & C & D & E & F \\
 A1 & B1 & \tikzmarknode[rounded rectangle,draw=red,inner sep=1pt,visible
 on=<2>,text opacity=1]{C1}{C1} & D1 & E1 & F1 \\
 A2 & B2 & C2 & D2 & E2 & F2 \\
 A3 & B3 & C3 & D3 & E3 & F3 \\
 A4 & B4 & C4 & D4 & E4 & F4 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw<2-> [ultra thick, red, {Latex[length=2mm,bend]}-] (C1.-25) to[out=-45,in=180,looseness=0.2] 
++(3.3,-0.1) 
node [right,text width=2.2cm, draw=red, very thick, fill=red!15!white, align=center, rounded corners=5pt] {\bf Appreciation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your code does not place the mark on slide 2

Comment: @Hany Now it does. Sorry, to me it was not clear that this is what you want when reading your question. After you told me, and I reread your question, I understand better what rectangle you mean in "I would like to draw the rectangle on slide 2", but before that I thought it was the additional rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately when I tried to compile your code I got the message "You have requested, on input line 48, version               `2012/12/07' of package l3names, but only version `2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitives' is available. ! Package expl3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX3 packages detected".  Would you please use my code to apply your idea. Thank you

Comment: @Hany I compiled my code on my updated TeXLive 2018 distribution with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex` without problems. When was the last time you updated your TeX installation? The error message suggests that you have not the latest files of `l3names`.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay of my response to your answer. We had a problem in the internet connection in my area for the last couple of weeks. I will try to install l3names package. Thank you again for your time.